# htaccess for addon domain and CMS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess is doing my head in. Any help from resident experts would be massively appreciated.

Here's the folder structure (this is a CMS so the folders don't actually exist, everything is rewritten via /index.php?it=foldername);

```
|--- home
   |--- folderOne
   |--- folderTwo
         |--- subfolderA
         |--- subfolderB
         |--- subfolderC
   |--- folderThree
   |--- etc
```

I have two domains and want the following:

- domain.com should point to the root folder (home) which it does, standard CMS setup.
- domainTwo.com (addon domain in cPanel, setup to also point to document root / so it also runs through /index.php) should redirect to /folderTwo and URL should be http://domainTwo.com, so rewrite should be something like /index.php?it=folderTwo
- additionally the page /folderTwo/subfolderA for example should be accessable from http://domainTwo.com/subfolderA.

I would have thought the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainTwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?it=folderTwo [L,QSA]

#standard CMS rewrite:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is driving me nuts, Anyone?

Comment: *"This is driving me nuts, Anyone?"* <-- No thanks. I would like to stay sane. :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why you can't just use `(.*)` to add the rest of the url to the path. I have also added a check to see if the file already exists. This prevents the rule from matching itself (because index.php exists) and prevents the rule from matching various other files, such as images, css or js files.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainTwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?it=folderTwo/$1 [L,QSA]

#standard CMS rewrite:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @Sumurai8, I was over-complicating it in my head I think, needed a / before folderTwo in your third line and it was all good, RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?it=/folderTwo [L,QSA], thanks a million :)

Comment: How would you then further rewrite the URL http://domainTwo.com/folderTwo to http://domainTwo/ without creating a loop?

Comment: By adding a rule before the other rules that has a condition that checks if it is `domaintwo.com`, then rewrites `^folderTwo/?(.*)$` to `$1` with a redirect&last flag (`[R,L]`).

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you Sumurai8. There is a lot of bad info on the net about apache rewrites I sometimes feel like I'm going in circles. I've learnt a surprising amount from your two answers, you are a gentleman and a scholar :-)